# In a custom Angular directive, pass the innerHTML as an attribute to another directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to take the innerHTML of an Angular directive, and pass that as an attribute of another directive. So, let's say that I have:

```
<js-code>This is some text</js-code>
```

my jsCode directive looks like this:

```
prettifyModule.directive('jsCode', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function($element, $scope) {
      $scope.codeText = $element.html();
      $element.replaceWith("<code-mirror model='codeText'></code-mirror>");
    }
  };
});
```

The goal being to pass a variable containing the string, "This is some text" as the `model` attribute of the `code-mirror` directive. For the most part, this seems to work. I can see in the elements that a directive appears that looks like:

```
<code-mirror model='codeText'></code-mirror>
```

However, the controller for the code-mirror directive does not, at that point, initialize.

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do this entirely, it would be appreciated.

My limitations are:

- I cannot alter the `code-mirror` directive.
- I cannot statically manipulate the text that is being sent to the `jsCode` directive.

Comment: Could you also put the code-mirror directive code in the question?

Comment: It is a black box. Here is the site where I got it from though http://a8m.github.io/angular-code-mirror/.

Comment: and here is a fiddle that uses a second directive of my making instead of code-mirror: http://jsfiddle.net/xw7ms0xd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the directive code to

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
return {
restrict: 'E',
link: function($scope, $element){
        $scope.codeText = $element.html();
      var template = "<second-directive model='codeText'></second-directive>";
      var linkFn = $compile(template);
      var content = linkFn($scope);
      $element.replaceWith(content);
},
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Text from controller";
}
};
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xw7ms0xd/2
This is the first time, I used $compile service. Got the reference from here 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, something else seems to be preventing me from getting this to work with code-mirror, but you've answered the question. Thanks. I wasn't aware of the compile service.